# javascript, adding in a comma after each API element

Tags: javascript, jquery

javascript, adding in a comma after each API element

I'd like to, after each SKU Element in my API calls, to add in a "," comma character. However, the way I'm currently doing it adds a comma at the very end too, just erroring out the javascript. Any ideas on what I should do?

These are in-house API elements, so please excuse me for posting them with my JS code, but it will give the bigger picture of what's going on because I'm providing them.

My code is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var rfk = rfk || [];
            rfk.push({"product_ids": [[[DMI:Use dmisource='((Cart)Container.DataItem).Items' ]]'[[DMI:Expression value='((CartItem)(Container.DataItem)).Sku']][[/DMI:Expression]]',[[/DMI:Use]]]});
 </script>
```

You can see that I placed my comma before the ending [[/DMI:Use]]

All that does for me is it makes the actual pushed out code look like this:

```
            var rfk = rfk || [];
            rfk.push({"product_ids": ['AR20','3081',]});
```

I'd like to have it look like this:

```
            var rfk = rfk || [];
            rfk.push({"product_ids": ['AR20','3081']});
```

Thus, therelin lies my problem.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript. i.e `'AR20','3081` is not a valid value for an object's property, use an array `['AR20','3081']`.

Comment: You need it to look like this {'product_ids': ['AR20', '3081']}

Comment: @user1879703 I'm afraid that last comment makes no sense.

Comment: If you give JavaScript an array that looks like `['AR20','3081',]`, it will automatically interpret it as `['AR20','3081']` anyway. Your concern seems unwarranted.

Comment: In my apis I usually have the server code loop through the string and remove any additional ','s that are in the return string.. but for this i suppose you could parse the {} out and then check the last char of the string and then put the {} back on to it..

Comment: There are single quotes and array enclosures all over the place in your code.

Comment: `[...].join(',')`, no?

Answer (score 0):

So you mean that this code:

```
[[[DMI:Use dmisource='((Cart)Container.DataItem).Items' ]]'[[DMI:Expression value='((CartItem)(Container.DataItem)).Sku']][[/DMI:Expression]]',[[/DMI:Use]]]
```

is a loop that, on the server-side, generates `['AR20','3081',]`, right?

Since `['AR20','3081',].length == 2`, that last comma doesn't do anything, but if you really need to fix it, then you could do it like this:

```
var rfk = rfk || [];
var values = "[[DMI:Use dmisource='((Cart)Container.DataItem).Items' ]][[DMI:Expression value='((CartItem)(Container.DataItem)).Sku']][[/DMI:Expression]],[[/DMI:Use]]";
/* the above should generate:
 * var values = "AR20,3081,";
 * but I'm not familiar with your code so that's my guess. */

// now remove a comma at the end o values string, then split it on remaing commas
var ids = values.replace(/,$/,'').split(',');
rfk.push( {"product_ids": ids });
```

A better solution would be to fix your in-house code to not generate a comma in last iteration.